# Выделение памяти C

Tags: c++, c

Задача заключается в сортировке записей. Ограничение по памяти - 8 мб. По подсчетам программа ест не более 5 мб., но на деле всё происходит иначе.

```
stroka = (char **)malloc(sizeof(char *) * 200000);
    for (int i = 0; i < 200000; i++) {
        stroka[i] = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char) * 25);
    }
```

Отладчик и диспетчер задач показывает, что памяти выделяется ~9 мб. Откуда берутся лишние 3-4 мб.? Что сделать, чтобы избежать этого?

Comment: А откуда взялось ограничение? Ну и память может выделять и стандартная библиотека.

Comment: а вы выделите 1 байт и посмотртие, сколко будет, `память = секция данные + секция кода`. А библиотеки могут вполне использовать оперативную память.

Comment: А объясните, откуда взялась ваша оценка в 5 мб?

Comment: Зачем насиловать свой мозг, когда много лет назад изобрели stl) - vector, map и т.д. и т.п., умные указатели, они намного упрощают жизнь программиста) используй их в своих проектах.

Comment: @VladD `200 000 * 25 ~ 5M`

Comment: На какую колонку в диспетчере задач вы смотрите?

Comment: @VladD ограничение взялось, скорее всего, из самого задания. см. timus.ru

Comment: автор вопроса, дайте лучше ссылку на задачу, мне кажется это XY проблема и хранить строки вообще не надо будет.

Comment: @alexolut: Ну, ограничения из конкурсных задач имеют мало практической ценности, поэтому аргументировать ими я бы посчитал неправильным. Кто не может решить конкурсную задачу, должен получить за неё свои справедливые 0 баллов.

Comment: @VladD на реальной олимпиаде интеренет не дадут, а после почему бы и не помочь разобраться с решением?

Comment: @pavel: Если это реально так (не конкурс, а примеры задач к нему), имеет смысл честно указать это в вопросе, и привести ссылку, чтобы обсуждение было полезно и другим.

Comment: [Задание](http://imcs.dvfu.ru/cats/static/problem_text-cpid-1057493.html)

Comment: мне кажется что эта задача легко решается https://habrahabr.ru/post/268535/ https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%92%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%88%D0%BD%D1%8F%D1%8F_%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0 или чем-то подобным.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

У `malloc` расход на управление как минимум 4-8 байт (ему ж надо где-то хранить размер, да?). Плюс выравнивание — вы никогда не получите ровно 25 байт, будет выравнивание на границу 16 байт — то есть, вместо 25 будет реально выделено 32 байта.

Кроме того, в режиме отладки в каждый блок ещё дописываются специальные байты для отлова выхода за границу блока.

Поэтому, если вы хотите охотиться за байтами, выделите себе всю нужную память одним куском, и работайте внутри.

---

Да, и не забывайте, что массив из 200000 указателей тоже отжирает 0.8 или 1.6 мегабайт, в зависимости от архитектуры.

Comment: Это дает, конечно же дает выигрыш в ((32 - 25) * 200000 + ~200000) байт, но это это значительно усложняет, казалось бы,  легкую задачу. К тому же, даже с таким выигрышем мы можем не пройти Memory Limit.

Comment: @KeltarHelviett: Хм, а почему вы считаете, что задача лёгкая с таким ограничением по памяти?

Comment: Всё упирается в ограничение по памяти, которое мы превышаем всего лишь в ~1.5 мб.

Comment: @KeltarHelviett: Ну да. Ограничение памяти на то и дано, чтобы не дать пользоваться стандартными средствами.

Answer (score 1):

Ну, вот как это можно выделить проще и без особых накладных расходов:

```
typedef char arr[200000][25];

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    arr& a = *(arr*)malloc(sizeof(arr));
    a[199999][24] = 'A';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

200000*8 - память которая выделена под указатели на платформе х-64;
200000*25 - память которая выделена под 200000 массивов по 25 байт каждого
нужно учитывать что при каждом обращении к малоку в памяти еще находится структура данных самого малока. + текст самой программы вот тебе и 9мб